# Set height and width for a JS slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, width

The JS below allows you to show a slideshow (carousel) with images randomly.

How do I show it in the browser with a certain width and height?
Let's give for example height: 800 and width: 100%?

I don't know if it's interesting but I'm creating the site with Boostrap 4.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript">
  
  var delay=1000 //set delay in miliseconds
  var curindex=0

  var randomimages=new Array()

    randomimages[0]="img/car1.jpg"
    randomimages[1]="img/car5.jpg"
    randomimages[2]="img/car2.jpg"
    randomimages[3]="img/car4.jpg"
    randomimages[4]="img/car3.jpg"
    randomimages[5]="img/car6.jpg"

  var preload=new Array()

  for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
  {
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
  }

  document.write('<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')

  function rotateimage()
  {

  if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length)))){
  curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
  }
  else
  curindex=tempindex

    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]
  }

  setInterval("rotateimage()",delay)

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a class...

```
  document.write('<img class="img-size" name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')
```

and in CSS file...

```
.img-size {
   width:800px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Or assign to width/height attributes...

```
  document.write('<img width="800px" height="100%" class="img-size" name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')
```

Comment: Great!! Just what I needed! I was losing my mind! to make it perfect I inserted 100vh and 100vw, and now it's perfect !! thank you so much!!

Comment: just one more thing, how could I add the fade effect between one img and another?